# No labelled objects found and xticks not rotated as desire for multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm creating 4 subplots using plt.subplots. There are several problems:

1. No labelled objects found   though I gave the labels. If I plot single plot, no error.
2. xticks not rotated as desire for multiple subplots like in lower left plot.

[image]
Any suggestion? Thank you.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    city_list = ["New York", "Atlanta", "Los Angeles","Chicago"]
    nrows = 2
    ncols = 2
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    axes_list = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist] 



   for i in range(len(city_list)):
       df = df1.loc[df1['city_name'] == city_list[i]]
       city_str = city_list[i]

       ax = axes_list.pop(0)
       ax.plot_date(df["local_date"], df["product_cnt"], '-',label = 'product_cnt')
       ax.plot_date(df["local_date"], df["usr_cnt"], '-',label = 'user_cnt')
       plt.legend(loc='upper left')
       plt.xticks(rotation=90)

       ax.set(title= city_str, ylabel='count', xlabel='Time')
       ax.autoscale_view()
   plt.savefig('DailyCnt.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to work on the respective axes object. So instead of `plt.legend()` use `ax.legend()` where `ax` is the respective axes. Also you want to rotate the xticklabels of the respective axes not those of the last subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

city_list = ["New York", "Atlanta", "Los Angeles","Chicago"]
n=30
cn = np.array([[c]*n for c in city_list]).T.flatten()
ld = np.repeat(pd.date_range("2012-01-01", periods=n, freq="2M"), len(city_list))
a = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=(len(city_list),n)), axis=1).flatten().astype(int)
b = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=(len(city_list),n)), axis=1).flatten().astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame({'city_name':cn,"local_date":ld, "product_cnt": a, "usr_cnt":b  })

nrows = 2
ncols = 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(len(city_list)):
    df1 = df.loc[df['city_name'] == city_list[i]]
    city_str = city_list[i]

    ax = axes.flat[i]
    ax.plot_date(df1["local_date"], df1["product_cnt"], '-',label = 'product_cnt')
    ax.plot_date(df1["local_date"], df1["usr_cnt"], '-',label = 'user_cnt')
    ax.legend()
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)

    ax.set(title= city_str, ylabel='count', xlabel='Time')
    ax.autoscale_view()

plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig('DailyCnt.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.